# Closed electric circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

Which one doesn’t work, why?

(a) DC 3.7v positive <-> light bulb  <->  same 3.7v negative: Normal closed circuit. Works OK.

(b) 3.7v positive <-> light bulb  <->  ground water pipe: Doesn’t work. Not a closed circuit?

(c) AC 220v live <-> light bulb  <->  220v neutral: Standard connection. Works.

(d) 220v live <-> light bulb  <->  220v ground: Shall also work? Did not try. It can be dangerous.

(e) 220v live <-> light bulb  <->  ground water pipe: Absolutely dangerous. Did not try.

Assume(d) is same as (e), shall work. Why not (b)?

Comment: Does a) mean you connect the two positive pols? than  it works not. in many houses the neutral of the AC is connected to the ground.

Comment: (a) a bulb connects to the positive and negative of the same 3.7v DC battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(b) isn't a closed circuit because the negative battery terminal and the water pipe aren't connected together.

(d) would, in a normal installation, be a closed circuit because the neutral is connected to the 220V ground where the mains enter the building.

(e) would, in a normal installation, be a closed circuit because the water pipe is electrically connected to the Earth and the neutral is connected to the Earth where the mains enter the building.